# Is there a way to have multi prefixes?

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to have multiple (around 2 or 3) prefixes, but I can't seem to find anything about it on the web.

I have tried some things, but I don't remember what.

What I have right now is:

```
const config = require("./configs.json");
const prefix = config.prefix;
rest of the code
```

and the config.json:

```
{
  "token": "not showing",
  "prefix": "irp",
}
```

Can someone please help? And if you have a solution please explain why this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how exactly are you defining your prefixes? Are you using a library? Are you doing it on your own?

If you're doing this on your own, it's quite simple. Lets say you're checking your prefixes by the js:

```js
.startsWith(prefix)
```

Then you can simply add boolean OR `||` to your check:

```js
.startsWith(prefix1) || .startsWith(prefix2)
```

Similarly if you're splitting the message and comparing the first argument you could do:

```js
args[0] == prefix1 || args[0] == prefix2
```

If you are using a 3rd party library on top of discord.js then you need to check that library's documentation for whether it allows multiple prefixes.

Comment: so i'm guessing this is a library? Did you check if it supports multiple prefixes?

Answer (score -1):

actually very easy.

```
"prefix": [ 'prefix1' , 'prefix2']
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation why/how this solves the OP's question.